# Strategy for combining rails and non-rails testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testunit

We've been happily using Test::Unit for our Rails application with the built-in tasks

```
rake test
rake test:units
rake test:functionals
rake test:integration
```

As we grow, we're getting a bunch of ruby code that doesn't relate to Rails at all. Mostly that goes into lib. I'd like to make it easy for people to add new tests for directories in lib that may or may not load the Rails environment, and have all the ruby tests run on rake:test. But it's not very clear to me what the preferred way is of extending `rake test`. Should we require one .rake file for each new directory? - that seems annoying.

Answer (score 0):

[Corey Haines](http://coreyhaines.com/) gives [talks on fast rails tests](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNn6M2vqxHE) which could be helpful for you.

Here is [an example app that demonstrates how you could layout tests that don't require rails](https://github.com/coreyhaines/ShoppingCart) (be sure to switch the branch to no_rails to see the final layout).

i.e. create extensions in `lib`, test them from `spec_no_rails`, call those extensions from your model, and run tests with `time rspec -fd -I lib/your_extension/ spec_no_rails/`

Answer (score -1):

You are unit testing the lib code, presumably, so it should go in test/unit/lib. If you want the lib code to be tested separately you could pull it out into gems.

Comment: But then the Rails environment will be loaded for those tests, which isn't necessary. Also, I feel like test/unit is just for testing models.

Comment: It sounds like you've got gem candidates if they're completely uncoupled from the rails environment. And test/unit isn't just for models, it's for any and all unit testing, e.g. helper tests.